# traversing a non binary tree in java

Tags: java, tree

I have a tree which is a non-binary tree and each node has more than 2 children.

I am looking for an algorithm to traverse the tree and print nodes, I am really new to learning data structure.

I know how to traverse a binary tree but I get lost when it comes to traversing a non-binary tree.

Could anyone give me a hint on how may I change the binary-tree traversal algorithm into a non-binary-tree traversal?

Assuming that we have the Binary tree traversal code using the DFS algorithm pre-order (Root-Left-Right).

```
public static class Node {
        private Integer val;
        private Node left;
        private Node right;
// setters and getters
}

public static void dfsPreOrderTraverseByRecursion(Node root) {
    if(root!=null) {
        System.out.println(root.getVal());
        dfsPreOrderTraverseByRecursion(root.getLeft());
        dfsPreOrderTraverseByRecursion(root.getRight());
    }
}
```

And this binary-tree

[image]

The above code should print it like this :

```
0
1
11
12
121
1211
122
2
21
```

In the case of the non-binary tree.
I need to modify the above code to traverse this tree in a similar way (Root-Left....Right)
[image]

With the new class Node as follows

```
public static class Node {
        private Integer val;
        private List<Node> children;
// setters and getters
}
```

And print the tree like this:

```
0
1
6
7
11
12
13
2
8
3
9
10
14
4
```

Comment: just traverse all the children from left to right, the rest is the same

Comment: @Ashalynd Please have a look at my answer

Comment: yes, that was what I meant

Answer (score 28):

In a non-binary tree, there will be a `Vector` or some other structure that has references to all the children. Make a recursive method as so:

```
public void traverse(Node child){ // post order traversal
    for(Node each : child.getChildren()){
        traverse(each);
    }
    this.printData();
}
```

Something along those lines.

Comment: This will do postorder traversal. Putting the printData before the for loop would cause a preorder traversal.

Answer (score 8):

Well, when traversing a binary tree, in preorder, you visit the parent node, then recursively traverse the left subtree then recursively traverse the right subtree. With a tree with more than two children, you recursively traverse the subtrees headed by each children. You would do the recursive calls in a for loop.

Comment: Hi Tarik- I'm not sure what you mean by `You would do the recursive calls in a for loop`- in what way can a for loop perform such recursive calls? It is iterative, no?

Comment: @Joseph Have a look at my pseudo-code :)

Comment: Thanks, I understand what Tarik meant not- not that the `for` loop is recursive, but that the recursive calls are made within a for loop. My mistake, thanks!

Comment: @LittleChild code illustrates what I described. Note that preorder, inorder and postorder are depth first traversals. You need to use a queue to do a breadth first traversal. You did not mention what type of traversal you want to do.

Comment: @Tarik BF traversal is a little bit more involved. OP does not mention what type of traversal is needed. If the OP clarifies, I  will upload a code snippet for DF traversal. 
*Shouldn't there be two Vectors for left and right children ?*

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to use recursion since you can't determine how many children are at each node (breadth) or how far the tree goes (depth). Depending on how you want to traverse, you can use  [Breadth-first-search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [Depth-first-search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

There is a ton of information on this topic, so give it an attempt to implement one of these recursive methods and please come back if you have trouble along the way!

Comment: You never "need to use recursion". There's no such thing as recursion on machine level, so the compiler, at latest, will produce an iterative solution. Cf. for postorder: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-postorder-traversal-of-n-ary-tree/

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm for pre-post order is the same as a binary tree.
There is no such thing as in-order traversal for a general tree i.e. does not make sense (unless *you* define some order)