# How do I find the nth node in a non-binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, language-agnostic, tree-traversal

I know how to traverse a binary tree, [using the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338009/traversing-a-non-binary-tree-in-java), but if I want to stop at, say, the 10th node in pre-order traversal, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you just run a pre-order traversal of the tree iterated n times? Every node you see on the pre-order traversal would increment the counter, and when counter == n stop grab the current node.

Pre-order traversal of course being root first, left most child recursive call, next left most child recursive call, ..., right most child recursive call

Comment: How do you keep track of n though? The given implementation for traversal uses recursion which complicates it in that aspect.

Comment: @DougSmith: One possibility: the recursive function takes an additional argument which is the maximum number of elements to traverse, and returns the number of elements actually traversed (which might be less). Another possibility: the visitor object maintains state, which includes the remaining count, and returns a boolean value to indicate whether or not the traverse should continue. (In this case, the recursive traverse would also have to return the same boolean indicator.)

Comment: Well, in a language-agnostic algorithm we simply track it outside of the recursive algorithm, incrementing it from within the algorithm. Language-agnostic algorithms aren't forced to consider memory management.

If we wanted to get implementation specific, most languages would support parameter based passing of a counter and n variable, or global variables could be used to track both variables

Comment: Understood, I'd like to keep it within the function and not involve external variables. Could you describe how you'd accomplish the parameter passing implementation?